# How to run Dusk test form URL in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I tried to run Dusk from an URL:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{

    $_SERVER['argv'] = [];
    Artisan::call('dusk');

});
```

And I did as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/245#issuecomment-297291671) and still cannot run the test from URL.

Comment: Why not write a [proper test](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#generating-tests) and visit the URL from there?

Comment: i have written test they run well . But everytime i need commandprompt for running the dusk tests . so i am searching a way so that i can run the dusk command from the url